# Can anyone provide a more detailed and/or logical etymology of the word denigrate?

Tags: etymology

According to wiktionary the word is said to derive from Latin 'denigratus,' to blacken; or asperse, defame. There's also Latin 'denigratio,' said to mean blackening.

Yet doesn't the prefix 'de' mean to take away from?

So wouldn't denigrare/denigro mean 'to remove the blackness of/from'?

I can't think of any other examples that would be consistent with this. Someone might say flammable / inflammable, but that at least makes some sense. Flammable = able to become flames. Inflammable = able to become inflamed/burned. That wouldn't really apply here.

Any help/thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Declaim, declare, denude, deplore, derelict, despoil, decoct, deliquesce, deny. To *denude* doesn't mean dressing. A *derelict* isn't something that has been returned. To *despoil* doesn't mean returning something plundered. Affixes like *de-* can mean more than one thing. Also, no matter the etymology, sometimes the current meaning of a word differs considerably. "Be nice," as the text above this box admonishes, would entail meaner or more foolish behavior from a 14th century computer user.

Comment: Thanks for the further examples; should have done some more contemplation/research first, but was bugging me and wanted to join the forum anyway.

Comment: Same sense of de- in Italian and French, denudare, déshabiller - declamare, declamer. Etc.

Answer (score 9):

Your concern appears to be the prefix de- which is used  in English also with the meaning of  “totally, completely”:

> from which   [denigrate](https://www.etymonline.com/word/denigrate) 
> 1520s, "to sully or stain" (the reputation, character, etc.), from Latin denigratus, past participle of denigrare "to blacken; to defame," ***from  de- "completely"***

***[de-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/de-?ref=etymonline_crossreference)***

> active word-forming element in English and in many verbs inherited from French and Latin, from Latin de "down, down from, from, off; concerning" (see de), also used as a prefix in Latin, usually meaning "down, off, away, from among, down from," ***but also "down to the bottom, totally" hence "completely" (intensive or completive), which is its sense in many English words.***

(Etymonline)

A few terms  with de- prefix with the connotation stated above:

> Decry, denote, demonstrative, default, devoid, deprivation, definitive, demean, demur, depravity, delusive, deportment, delude, decrepitude , desiccate, demure.

Comment: Thank you. Despoil does not appear to be one, its etymology means to strip the skin/hide off something; but the others esp declare, denude seem to be consistent. As for the comment function, I was not aware. In most forums, the answer function is used to respond to OP; my mistake. Seems like I ruffled some feathers.

Comment: @fringehist1980 I apologize if you have found your first encounter here a less than felicitous one.  Your question is a good one, but it would benefit from a little research. If you have a limited number of questions I will try to help you...but first, visit the [Help Page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) for advice on posting  on Q&A

Comment: No problem; I understand the need for it, otherwise somewhat off-topic back-and-forths can gum up the forum and appear to be major debates when aren't. Will do; thanks